# How to design a friend list in sql /sqlite

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite, node-sqlite3

Im relatively new to sql and Im trying to create a relationship between two users.
A friend request has to be sent and accepted to be friends with each other. Now I have a third table called items. A user should now be able to see all items that are owned by his friends. Im kinda stuck writing this query...

item table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item(
                    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
                    owner VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                    borrowedBy VARCHAR(50),
                    imageUrl TEXT
                );
```

friendship table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS friendship(
            friendship_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL
        );
```

user_friendship

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_friendship(
        username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        friendship_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        status INTEGER NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (username, friendship_id)
    );
```

Comment: What is your question? Please show sample data, actual results and expected results.

Comment: what's the meaning of your friendship table here please give more useful info

Comment: you may need to optimize your structure

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at tutorials on how to build a SQL database, mainly on table relationship.

Here, for example, you don't need separate friendship and user_friendship table.

You could have one friendship table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS friendship(
        friendship_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        username1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        username2 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        status INTEGER NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (friendship_id, username1 , username2  )
    );
```

Note that you should use integer value for foreign keys, not varchar(50).